# c++ convert hexadecimal string with ":" to original "binary" string

Tags: c++, encryption

I have the following code to convert an encrypted ciphertext to a readable hexadecimal format:

```
std::string convertToReadable(std::string ciphertext)
{
    std::stringstream outText;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ )
        outText << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << ":";

    return outText.str();
}
```

The readable result of this function is something as:

```
56:5e:8b:a8:04:93:e2:f1:5c:20:8b:fd:f5:b7:22:0b:82:42:46:58:9b:d4:c1:8e:ac:62:85:04:ff:7f:c6:d3:
```

Now I need to do the way back, converting the readable format to the original `ciphertext` in order to decrypt it:

```
std::string convertFromReadable(std::string text)
{
    std::istringstream cipherStream;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++ )
    {
        if (text.substr(i, 1) == ":")
            continue;

        std::string str = text.substr(i, 2);
        std::istringstream buffer(str);
        int value;
        buffer >> std::hex >> value;
        cipherStream << value;
    }

    return cipherStream.str();
}
```

This is not absolutely working, as I´m getting the wrong string back.

How can I fix the `convertFromReadable()` so that I can have the original `ciphertext` back ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you heard of `const` and references

Comment: worth having a lookat 'bitset'

Comment: Ed, please clearly elaborate your point..

Comment: TBH I wouldn't use formatted i/o for the output.. instead push_back onto a string or vector<unsigned char>

Comment: @Mendez: example of Ed's point: no need to pass the `text` argument *by value*, since you won't modify it inside `convertFromReadable`. Passing by `const` reference happens if you change the argument to `...(const std::string& text)`.  Same for `convertToReadable`.

Comment: Please don't provide a solution in the question. That might confuse future readers. You can ask the answerer to provide code or submit your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are problems that you should fix before debugging this any further:

- `cipherStream` should be `ostringstream`, not `istringstream`
- The `for` loop should stop two characters before the end. Otherwise your `substr` is going to fail. Make the loop condition `i+2 < text.size()`
- When you read two characters from the input, you need to advance `i` by two, i.e. add `i++` after the `std::string str = text.substr(i, 2);` line.
- Since you want character output, add a cast to `char` when writing the data to `cipherStream`, i.e. `cipherStream << (char)value`

Answer (score 1):

Good you got your code working. Just thought I'd illustrate a slightly simpler, more direct approach using streams without the fiddly index tracking and substr extraction:

```
std::string convertFromReadable(const std::string& text)
{
    std::istringstream iss(text);
    std::ostringstream cipherStream;
    int n;
    while (iss >> std::hex >> n)
    {
        cipherStream << (char)n;
        // if there's another character it better be ':'
        char c;
        if (iss >> c && c != ':')
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid character in cipher");
    }
    return cipherStream.str();
}
```

Note that after the last hex value, if there's no colon the `if (iss >> c...` test will evaluate `false` as will the `while (iss >> ...` test, fallingt through to return.